# Loading Qt plugins when linking to Qt statically?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, svg, icons

I'm trying to use SVG graphics in QIcons. I have a static library that contains all my graphics resources, and a method in that static library that returns QIcons pre-loaded with the correct graphics. I'm trying to do this:

```
QIcon icon(":/icons/find.svg");
```

I have verified that that resources has been loaded by listing it with QDir:

```
qDebug() << QDir(":/icons/").entryList();
```

However, the SVG icon is not being shown. When I change the icon loading code to this:

```
QIcon icon(":/icons/find.png");
```

everything works correctly.

The problem seems to be that the SVG plugin never gets loaded. I can get a list of supported image types, which contains:

> ("bmp", "pbm", "pgm", "png", "ppm", "xbm", "xpm")

but no mention of SVG.

I've made sure I'm using the SVG module in both my static library .pro file, and my main application .pro file.

**Edit:**

It seems the problem is that I am linking to Qt statically, and thus the plugins are all static libs. The documentation for `QPluginLoader` states that:

> Note that the QPluginLoader cannot be
>   used if your application is statically
>   linked against Qt. In this case, you
>   will also have to link to plugins
>   statically. You can use QLibrary if
>   you need to load dynamic libraries in
>   a statically linked application.

Yet statically linking to these plugins seems to do nothing ( the list of supported image formats does not grow).

**Edit2:**

Also, linking to Qt dynamically (after rebuilding my whole app) makes the code above work perfectly. However, I *want* to link to Qt statically, so the question looks now to be more about loading Qt plugins when linking to Qt statically and less about icons in general. I will update the post title to reflect this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN.

See the documentation here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtplugin.html#Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtsvg.html), the way to load a svg icon is:

```
QSvgRenderer svgRenderer( ":/icons/find.svg" );
Q_ASSERT( svgRenderer.isValid());

QImage img( svgRenderer.defaultSize() );
QPainter p( &img );
svgRenderer.render( &p );
p.end();

QIcon icon( QPixmap::fromImage( img ) );
```

For your link problem, QtSvg is part of Qt, so you do not need to add it as a plugin. The only thing required to compile with SVG support is :

```
QT += svg
```

Comment: For normal applications, yes. However, icons are different. The QIcon docs (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qicon.html) hint that with the svg icon engine you should be able to load SVG images directly into QIcons. Other people have had this work as well (http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2008-07/thread00105-0.html) just not in a static context.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that the above comment is ambiguous. "applications" in the first sentence is meant as in "uses", not as in "application programmes".